# How to distribute a JAR file with Classes to other developers?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I need to distribute some compiled JAVA classes to another development team. So I can JAR up the compiled classes.

However my Java classes also depends on libraries A, B and C.

What is the most professional way to do this?

- How do I in a gradle project include a custom JAR file located somewhere in the filesystem?

And how do I communicate the dependencies towards the other development team:

- "Compile" all dependencies into my JAR. However this can cause (version) conflicts at their side.
- Provide the plain JAR with my own JAR files, and provide a Gradle snippet with dependencies which they should include in their Gradle project (or ANT/Maven or just what they use).

Is there a way to:

- Write a Gradle file which pull in the JAR on a local file system, and also all dependencies, e.g. by describing them in the gradle file?
- Include a Gradle/Manifest file into the compiled JAR file ("self describing" JAR file), which is automatically read by Gradle and automatically all dependencies are picked up?

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: The real best way to do this is to provide the developers with the source code so that they can build it themselves!  (Also the most professional, IMO)

Comment: "Compile" all dependencies into my JAR.  This is one of the best ways. The other developers don't have to worry about the versions of the other libraries. Even if there are any new versions of those libraries, your own class file knows from which version to to be dependent on.

Comment: Or better still, set up a source code repository AND an artifact repository repository to hold the JAR files, etc.  And give the other team access to the repository.

Comment: @Sara - That is a good approach when delivering code to non-developer customers.  But developers need to know what the dependencies are, and (often) have the ability to tinker with them.  And having access to source code is going to make it easier for them to debug their code and find / report bugs in your code!

Comment: I would suggest to follow how Oracle follows while distribution. A separate jar for the actual class with its dependencies and another jar with the source file.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most professional way to do this?

The recommended way is to use a [Maven Repository Manager](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) such as [Sonatype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.org/nexus/go/).

Make sure you [configure a single repository group](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/maven-repositories#MavenRepositories-ConfiguringApacheMaven).

You can then deploy your SNAPSHOT and release artifacts using `mvn clean deploy` (with Maven) or some equivalent if you're using another build tool such as Gradle.

Make sure you also deploy the source jars, so that the developers can easily access the sources from within their IDEs.

With Maven:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.1</version>
      </plugin>
      [...]
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

<plugins>
   [...]
   <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
   </plugin>
   [...]
</plugins>
```

As long as the deployed `pom.xml` files declare all dependencies, build tools which support Maven dependencies will make sure they also download all transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You need an artefact manager such as artifactory (https://jfrog.com/open-source/).

You can then write a gradle script to build your jar, and publish it to the artifactory server, along with all of its dependencies. If the dependencies are publicly available there will be no need to publish them, since the artifactory server will have links to online repositories (e.g. jcenter, mavencentral).
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin

```
plugins {
   id 'maven-publish'
   id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.15.2"
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "http://repo.mycompany.com/artifactory"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }       
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
           groupId = 'com.mycompany'
           artifactId = 'myproject'
           version = '1.0'
           from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Your colleagues can then write a maven or gradle script which specifies that jar and downloads it, and all of its dependencies.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/artifactory"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.mycompany', name: 'myproject', version:'1.0'
}
```

This kind of dependency management is what build tools like maven and gradle are for.

Answer (score 0):

One way do this is:
Make a service with all your source file that you want to share. Name this service something like "developer-dependency-sdk".
Your POM of your this service will look something like this:

```
<groupId>your.company</groupId>
<artifactId>developer-dependency-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>project-id</id>
        <url>http://your_repository/server</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Now, any other project can use the image in their project image as a dependency:

```
 <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>project-id</id>
      <name>Dependency Repository</name>
      <url>https://your_repository/server</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

The above POM section will tell your current project to pick the dependencies from the URL provided. After this, you can simply add your dependency.
Check this [link](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) for more specifics.